# How to Access Window Object declared in App.xaml in class file in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have  Window object in App.xaml.cs file which is public. Now, i want to access this window object in class file. Is it possible?

In App.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
         public MyWindow mainWindowObj;

        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            mainWindowObj = new MyWindow();
            mainWindowObj.Show();
        }
    }
```

In Some Classfile.cs i want to access the 'mainWindowobj'. I have tried following in Classfile.cs but error:

```
((App)Application.Current).mainWindowObj.Title="Hello";
```

this above line is sample i want to access the variables,objects inside this forms.

Help Appreciated!

Comment: what error? and is this app really WPF or is it a win-form app?

Comment: hello @Viv the error is at line .Current it says: System.Windows.Forms.Application doesnt contain defination for 'Current'. any solution?

Comment: well `System.Windows.Forms.Application` is not what you want, switch `((App)Application.Current).mainWindowObj.Title="Hello";` to `(System.Windows.Application.Current as App).mainWindowObj.Title="Hello";`

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to an answer.

Namespace being used for `Application` appears to be [System.Windows.Forms.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.aspx) rather than [System.Windows.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx)

**fix** : (be explicit if needed or get rid of the `using System.Windows.Forms;` which you probably have somewhere in that scope)

```
var currentApp = System.Windows.Application.Current as App;
if (currentApp != null)
  currentApp.mainWindowObj.Title = "Hello";
```

Comment: that is why i am waiting to vote up to your answer..! :) so voted as usefull answer before...!